# Set text gravity center in square Frame layout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-framelayout

I need set text in *center* `FrameLayout`, but if I `setGravity` *center* it will be *center* only *horizontal*.
I create Square Frame layout.

```
public class SquareFrameLayout extends FrameLayout {
public SquareFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public SquareFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public SquareFrameLayout(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, @AttrRes int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int size = width < height ? height:width;
    setMeasuredDimension(size,size);
}

<com.example.student.game.SquareFrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/GameButtonFrameLayout"
    android:background="#beb7b7"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:clickable="true">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/GameButtonText" />
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/GameButtonImage"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</com.example.student.game.SquareFrameLayout>
```

but if I set gravity - `Gravity.CENTER` to `textView` which is in `SquareFrameLayout`, gravity sets only center *horizontal*.

Comment: can you show me your xml code too.

Comment: I can't know exactly because we can't see your xml, but in the past I've found that my height was set to wrap_content instead of match_parent. I hope this helped

Comment: I have added XML, height is set match_parent.

Comment: maybe try: android:layout_centerInParent="true", but set height and width to wrap_content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add gravity center in your text view .
Hope this helps .